# Как создать несколько произвольных типов записи в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть некоторый код который в админке выводит произвольный тип записи, мне нужно несколько таких типов вот как я это вывожу

Как объявить еще один тип?

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types_1' );
    function register_post_types_1(){
        register_post_type('post_type_name', array(
            'label'  => null,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'               => 'Вакансии', // основное название для типа записи
                'singular_name'      => 'Career', // название для одной записи этого типа
                'add_new'            => 'Добавить позицию', // для добавления новой записи
                'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление позиции', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
                'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование ____', // для редактирования типа записи
                'new_item'           => 'Новое ____', // текст новой записи
                'view_item'          => 'Смотреть позицию', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
                'search_items'       => 'Искать позицию', // для поиска по этим типам записи
                'not_found'          => 'Позиция не найдена', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Позиция не найдена в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
                'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
                'menu_name'          => 'Вакансии', // название меню
            ),
            'description'         => '',
            'public'              => true,
            // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
            // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
            'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
            // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
            'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
            'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
            'menu_position'       => null,
            'menu_icon'           => null,
            //'capability_type'   => 'post',
            //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
            //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'supports'            => [ 'title', 'editor' ], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
            'taxonomies'          => [],
            'has_archive'         => false,
            'rewrite'             => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-id-alt', // иконка в меню
        ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете добавить ещё один action для ещё одной функции, получится что-то вроде:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types_1' );
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types_2' );
function register_post_types_1(){
    register_post_type('post_type_name', array(
        // все ваши параметры
    ));
}

function register_post_types_2(){
    register_post_type('post_other_type_name', array(
        // все ваши параметры для второго типа постов
    ));
}
```

Или регистрировать все типы постов внутри одной функции:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types_all' );
function register_post_types_all(){
    register_post_type('post_type_name', array(
        // все ваши параметры
    ));

    register_post_type('post_other_type_name', array(
        // все ваши параметры для второго типа постов
    ));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого типа поста, нужен новый post_type. Но если вам нужны разные категории одного поста, посмотри в сторону register_taxonomy, уменьшит количество кода и создаст гибкость в работе.